# how to change the value of a Div according to whats typed into a form input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know if I want to change the value of an input on a form according to what a user types into another input using:

```
$('#inputName').change(function() {
    $('#inputURL').val($('#inputName').val());
});
```

But I'd like to have it so when someone types into the input it updates a Div with the text instead. IE they type into #inputName and this happens:

```
<div id="personsName"> text appears here as they type</div>
```

How'd I go about doing that? I doesn't work when I change #inputURL into #personsName :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `change` event is only triggered when leaving the textfield, so use `keypress` instead if you really want to "update the text on typing into a text field". `.val` only applies to form elements which actually have a value (e.g. `<input>` and `<textarea>` elements). In all other cases, you need the `text` method for modifying the text .

```
$("#inputName").keypress(function () {
    $("#personName").text(this.value);
});
```

You can test this code here: http://jsfiddle.net/ntBnA/

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there:

```
$('#inputName').change(function() {
    $('#personsName').text($('#inputName').val());
});
```

Comment: The `change` event only fires when focus on the element changes after content has changed, not on keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Cache this bad boy, its being repeatedly used!
var personsName = $('#personsName');

$('#inputName').bind({
  keyup: function () {
    //This is what you want.
    personsName.text($(this).val());
  },
  change: function () {
    //This is what you were doing.  See the difference?
    $('#inputURL').val($(this).val());
  }
});
```